# Is there a source displaying when and where a word was first attested?

Tags: english, resource-request, lexicon

Is there a source at which one can find out when and where a word first came into use/print? Especially interested in scientific discourse.

Comment: This site may help: [link](https://www.etymonline.com/)

Answer (score 3):

The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/) quotes early attestations for most of the words in the dictionary. The latest edition is available online, but most of the entries require a payed subscription to access them.

The first edition is out of copyright and available for free at archive.org (links to each volume are given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary#1st_edition)).